# Appengine - Deployment appcfg.py vs git

Tags: google-app-engine

I've recently started with Appengine and I'd been using the regular old deployment method using `appcfg.py`.

Now I want to start deployment using release pipelines. I created a pipeline in my Project settings, then authenticated myself in gcloud.

Now if I do `gcloud init myproj-id`, I should theoretically get the content of my project pulled from the server right? But that doesn't happen.

https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/gcloud/reference/init

> If you have enabled push-to-deploy in the Cloud Console, one of the
>   things that gcloud init will do for you is cloning the Google-hosted
>   git repository associated with PROJECT

So, my questions:

1. Why is the content not pulled?
2. What happens if I push my project via git now? How would Appengine manage my previously deployed project via appcfg.py versus my git push'd project?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the content not pulled?

Did you configure your repository by using the *Configure your repository* link at the top of the pipeline configuration page?

> What happens if I push my project via git now? How would Appengine manage my previously deployed project via appcfg.py versus my git push'd project?

Unless you use different versions, App Engine won't make a difference; your git pushed project will overwrite your previous one.